# Iterate value from java class to jsp in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Here i come with a problem to iterate a value from java to jsp by action class but it cant iterate value and display a value.i am new to strut2 kindly guide to go further

Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Error building results for action VBA in namespace / - action - file:/home/android/workspace/sent/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Structlibary/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:12:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:340)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:429)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: No result type specified for result named 'success', perhaps the parent package does not specify the result type? - result - file:/home/android/workspace/sent/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Structlibary/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:13:27
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:575)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:338)
    ... 26 more
```

Beantest:

```
public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBook()
    {
        return Book;
    }

    public void setBook(String book)
    {
        Book = book;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        Author = author;
    }

    public String getAvailbleqty()
    {
        return Availbleqty;
    }

    public void setAvailbleqty(String availbleqty)
    {
        Availbleqty = availbleqty;
    }

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category)
    {
        Category = category;
    }
```

DataAction.java:

```
public List<Beantest> viewbook()
    {

        List<Beantest> al=new ArrayList<Beantest>();
        Beantest bt = new Beantest();
        try
        {
            String sql = "select * from Bookavaible";
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                bt.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                bt.setBook(rs.getString("Book"));
                bt.setAuthor(rs.getString("Author"));
                bt.setAvailbleqty(rs.getString("Availbleqty"));
                bt.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
                al.add(bt);
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return al;

    }
```

Actiontest.java

```
public class ActionTest {
Beantest bt;
DataAction da;

 public String viewbookaction()
 {
    da=new DataAction();
    List<Beantest> al=da.viewbook();
    ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("view", al);
    System.out.println("View User" + al);
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

 }
}
```

Bookview.jsp:

```
<s:action name="VBA">
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <s:iterator value="view" var="viewbook">

                <td>id:<s:property value="#viewbook.getId" /></td>

                <td>Book:<s:property value="#viewbook.getBook" /></td>

                <td>Author:<s:property value="#viewbook.getAuthor" /></td>

                <td>Availbleqty:<s:property value="#viewbook.getAvailbleqty" /></td>

                <td>Category:<s:property value="#viewbook.getCategory" /></td>

                <td>Action:</td>
            </s:iterator>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </s:action>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>BookView.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

strut2.xml

```
<package name="a" namespace="/">

        <action name="VBA" class="Action.ActionTest" method="viewbookaction">
            <result name="success">/BookView.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package should extend `struts-default`, e.g.,

```
<package name="a" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Sort of like in every example.

---

Unrelated, but the following code bothers me for a few reasons:

```
public class ActionTest {
Beantest bt;
DataAction da;

    public String viewbookaction() {
        da = new DataAction();
        List<Beantest> al = da.viewbook();
        ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("view", al);
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

First, it's my opinion that variables should be declared as close as possible to their use, e.g.,

```
public class ActionTest {
    public String viewbookaction() {
        DataAction da = new DataAction();
```

Second, one of the main points of S2 (for better or worse) is that by default, the action itself is used as a sort-of view-layer component. Values intended for the view layer should be properties of the action; there is rarely a reason to access the request directly, e.g.,

```
public class ActionTest {
    private List<Beantest> beans;

    public String viewbookaction() {
        DataAction da = new DataAction();
        beans = da.viewbook();
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Beantest> getBeans() {
        return beans;
    }
}
```

Now the list is available in the JSP via `${beans}` (for JSTL) or `%{beans}` if using OGNL.

Further, I'd extend `ActionSupport` (there are legitimate reasons not to, but none here) and remove intermediate variables:

```
public class ActionTest extends ActionSupport {
    private List<Beantest> beans;

    public String viewbookaction() {
        beans = (new DataAction()).viewbook();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Beantest> getBeans() {
        return beans;
    }
}
```

Depending on the actual usage this might reduce even further to:

```
public class ActionTest extends ActionSupport {
    public List<Beantest> getBeans() {
        return (new DataAction()).viewbook();
    }
}
```

Comment: Again it showing some error like org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /BookView.jsp(15,3) Attribute var invalid for tag iterator according to TLD

Comment: @user3607180 Because you're using a version different than the docs you're reading. Older versions use `id`, newer versions use `var`.